# NameError: name 'D' is not defined

Tags: python

I get the following error when I try running my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    D
NameError: name 'D' is not defined
```

I dont know what is causing the error.

I am trying to test if `D C:\Test\Project1\Example`  is valid or not

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

def read_input_vaild():
    '''read input and consider if vaild'''
    while True:
        input_dir = input()
        path_dir = input_dir[2:]
        p = Path(path_dir)

        if input_dir[0] == 'D' and input_dir[1] == ' ':
            if p.exists() and p.is_dir:
                return input_dir
            else:
                print('ERROR')
                input_dir = read_input_vaild()
                return input_dir
        else:
            print('ERROR')
            input_dir = read_input_vaild()
            return input_dir
```

Comment: The problem is enter D follow by a space and then path

Comment: why D is there in path ?

Comment: it is the input format : D follow by a space, follow a path

Comment: You must be using Python2.x -- In which case you should use `raw_input` instead of `input` The problem is `input` is trying to evaluate your input to Python code, but you want a string instead. Alternatively, run in Python3 and it shouldn't produce that problem.

Comment: I am using Python3 right now, so I wonder why I got this question

Comment: The Traceback says the error is *in* line one - are you showing us the complete module? If you copy and paste the code in your post, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Python2.x -- In which case you should use raw_input instead of input The problem is input is trying to evaluate your input to Python code, but you want a string instead.

If you were using Python3.x `input` would work fine and would always be a string.

So, change

```
    input_dir = input()
```

to

```
    input_dir = raw_input()
```

Comment: I am using Python3 right now, so I wonder why I got this question

Comment: You must be mistaken. Double-check the version by running the following code `import sys;print(sys.version)` -- If you are, in fact, using Python3, then the code in the question will not produce that problem. If you're still having issues, please update the question with the full traceback message and more details on exactly how you're running the code.

Comment: 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you doing `python3 my_file.py` ? A common mistake is to do `python my_file.py` which refers to the system-installed version of Python, which is Python2 for Mac OS.